# Holoviews - Heatmap - Different color scale per each row of data

Tags: python, panel, holoviews

I would like to have a different conditional formatting for each row shown in the heatmap - that is, colors should be the same but the scale should be applied independently for each row.

Picking up on the example in this link: [Us Unemployment — HoloViews v1.15.1](https://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/us_unemployment.html)

```
from bokeh.sampledata.unemployment1948 import data

data = pd.melt(data.drop('Annual', 1), id_vars='Year', var_name='Month', value_name='Unemployment')
heatmap = hv.HeatMap(data, label="US Unemployment (1948 - 2013)")

colors = ["#75968f", "#a5bab7", "#c9d9d3", "#e2e2e2", "#dfccce", "#ddb7b1", "#cc7878", "#933b41", "#550b1d"]
heatmap.opts(
    opts.HeatMap(width=900, height=400, xrotation=45, xaxis='top', labelled=[],
                 tools=['hover'], cmap=colors))
```

What I would like is for January’s row color scale to be independent of the other months shown in the y-axis. So that different values in December (for the different years), for example, don’t affect the colors of January’s row.

Is it possible?

I provide a different example below (here month are on the x-axis instead of y-axis):

[image]

As you can see the difference from the normal to the intended result is that in the normal result the conditional formatting is applied to the entire dataframe/matrix while in intended result it is applied to each row independently.

Comment: Does it need to be a HeatMap, or can you use Panel's Tabulator support for this (https://panel.holoviz.org/reference/widgets/Tabulator.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I could find an answer to the problem.
I posted my code in here in case someone comes here in the future: https://github.com/vlaranjo/Vasconomics_Materials/blob/master/Articles/Stock%20Market%20Returns%20Seasonality/Code%20Conditional%20Formatting%20for%20Each%20Row%20HeatMap.ipynb

The answer lies in running a loop of heatmaps and defining the label in a specific way:

```
heatmap = hv.HeatMap(data, label=f"Year {heatmap_row}")
```